# How can I lock the rotation of a player in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, z-axis

I'm currently making a 2D game as a beginner and I made a spinning platform. But when it's rotating the player's rotation (z-axis) also changes because it's a child of the platform. I need this when I use moving platforms. Now I want to lock the z-axis of the rotation of the player. I already tried it in 3 different ways, but none of them seems to be working. Does anybody know how to do this?

These are the three ways I tried:

```
// 1
PlayerTrans.transform.Rotate(
    PlayerTrans.transform.rotation.x, 
    PlayerTrans.transform.rotation.y, 
    0);

// 2
PlayerTrans.transform.Rotate(
    PlayerTrans.transform.rotation.x, 
    PlayerTrans.transform.rotation.y, 
    0, 
    Space.Self);

// 3
PlayerTrans.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(
    PlayerTrans.transform.localEulerAngles.x, 
    PlayerTrans.transform.localEulerAngles.y, 
    0f));
```

and this is, what my code looks like for staying on the moving platforms. I used raycasting for this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Raycasting : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    Transform PlayerTrans;
    public float RayCastRange = 3;
    void Start()
    {
        PlayerTrans = transform.parent;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit2D PlattformCheck = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector2.up, RayCastRange);

        if (PlattformCheck.collider != null)
        {
            if (PlattformCheck.collider.gameObject.tag == "Platform")
            {
                PlayerTrans.transform.SetParent(PlattformCheck.collider.gameObject.transform);
            }
            else
            {
                PlayerTrans.transform.SetParent(null);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerTrans.transform.SetParent(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to just detect if the player is on the platform via raycast, then access the object’s movement script. Make sure in the movement script there is a velocity variable of type Vector3. You should then add a velocity variable to the player, and set the velocity to the platform’s velocity. And apply the velocity to both objects. I could send the code in a script if you want.

Comment: Don't make the player a child of the platform! Rather create a script that follows the movement of the platform but without parenting anything

Comment: @ken yeah that would be nice, thank you so much!

Comment: @derHugo Is that complicated?

Comment: Is your player a rigidbody or a normal transform?

Comment: @derHugo It has both components, so I would say rigidbody

Comment: In this case you don't want to use parenting or the `Transform` component at all (also in your other rotation Platform script btw) .. I imagine the platform is a rigidbody ad well? Then you could either look into [Joints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Joints2D.html).. alternatively you could implement a script that copies the position of the platform but allows to maintain a certain dynamic offset which allows your player to move relative to the platform .. is it complicated .. a little bit yes, I'd say .. especially since I'm only on a phone right now ^^

Comment: @derHugo I understand, I guess, but the problem is, that the platform is a transform and I'm a beginner xD

Comment: @JonathanXD12 did you see my answer? Does it not work how you wanted, or does it not work at all?

Comment: @ken Yeah, sorry, so I need to make 2 new scripts in Unity and put the codes you made in there right?

Comment: Yes. Make you have read what I wrote, because you need to name them certain names. If there are any errors, tell me. Change the 0.1f value in the first value to about half the height of the player plus a small value.

Comment: @ken okay, thank you I will try it tomorrow :)

Comment: @ken Assets/Raycasting.cs(5,6): error CS0111: Type '<invalid-global-code>' already defines a member called 'Update' with the same parameter types

Comment: @derHugo "Don't make the player a child of the platform! Rather create a script that follows the movement of the platform but without parenting anything" Could you make me one pls?

Comment: @JonathanXD12 the problem is that unity contains a class called raycasting, and that is used for actually casting rays. You need to change the name of the class to something unity does not already contain. Like “Player-Raycast”.

Comment: @ken now it says: Assets/Player_Raycast.cs(5,44): error CS1513: } expected

Comment: Did you close the class and update and if statement with the }, and if you did, do you have any extra brackets, parentheses, or curly braces? Update question with your full code including the class and ‘using UnityEngine’ part of it. Tell me if you get more errors because I just realized you are using 2D.

Answer (score 0):

You should raycast directly down and then apply velocities to both objects (un-child the player from the platforms). You could do something like this for the player:

```cs
public LayerMask mask; //set ‘mask’ to the mask of the
//platform in the Unity Editor.
public Vector3 velocity;

void Update()
{
  RaycastHit hit;
  if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, out hit, 0.1f, mask))
  //0.1f is the distance to the platform to be able to be moved by the platform.
  {
    velocity = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Platform>().velocity;
  }
  float h = Input.GetAxis(“Horizontal”);
  //this one is for CharacterController:
  cc.Move(velocity);
  //this one is for rigidbody:
  rb.velocity = velocity;
  velocity = 0;
}
```

It takes the velocity from the ‘Platform’ script and moves the player based on it. Now we should add the platform script. Call it ‘Platform’.

```cs
public Vector3 velocity;
public Vector3 a; //a and b are the two points you want the platform to go between.
public Vector3 b;

public float period = 2f; //the amount of seconds per cycle.
float cycles;

void Update()
{
  cycles = Time.time / period;
  float amplitude = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.PI * 2f * cycles);
  Vector3 location = Vector3.Lerp(a, b, amplitude);
  velocity = transform.position - location;
  transform.position = velocity;
}
```

This script interpolates between the point a and b, then it finds the velocity and applies it. The player takes this velocity and it moves the player. Comment if you found an error.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways that might help you:

1. Just freeze the rotation from the inspector:

[image]

2. you can use some LookAt function (there is one for 3D but you can look and find ones for 2D) and just look at the camera.

(if you cant find it let me know and I will add it)